# JPQL pagination giving wierd results

Tags: oracle, jpa, pagination, jpql

I'm using spring 3.2 and Hibernate JPA with oracle 10g configuration.
I have to display records of a table in pages of 10 records, which has a total of 28 records presently.

So I prepare a persistence Query and set it's `FirstResult` and `MaxResult`:

```
String sql = "From instanceDetailLog Where formName='GPB' Order By instanceId";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);

query.setFirstResult(((pageNumber*recordsToFetch)-recordsToFetch));
query.setMaxResults((pageNumber*recordsToFetch));

List<Object> dataList = query.getResultList();
```

Initially for records 1-10 the records are fetched properly. But When I request for the next page for records 11-20, it gives me 18 records (All of the remaining records) and in the third page I get repeating records.

I had stumbled upon this [**article**](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpql-pagination-oracle). Which describes about an issue with pagination in oracle and JPA.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaxResults should be a constant recordsToFetch.  Using pageNumber*recordsToFetch you are telling it to fetch 20 rows, which is why you are getting the last 18.

Comment: your right it should be a constant but i'm also setting the firstResult which is basically telling it to start reading from the specified record

Comment: You are specifying the max number of results to return.  It is independent from the firstResult setting.  If you want 10 each time, specify 10 each time.

Comment: So your saying MaxResults does not specify the record number upto which it should read but the amount of records it fetches